# error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::on_Input_A_textChanged(QString const&)'

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I ran into a weird problem that I can't seem to understand.
I'm new to the c++ Qt creator and I'm programming a little calculator.
But I'm getting this problem:

error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::on_Input_A_textChanged(QString             const&)

And this is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QString"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::on_add_clicked()
{
double a,b,c;

a = ui->Input_A->text().toDouble();
b = ui->Input_B->text().toDouble();

c = a + b;

ui->Result->setText(QString::number(c));
}
```

I don't use the function out of the error so I don't know whats wrong?
I'm using lineEdits and they are named: Input_A, Input_B, Result.

edit:
Here is the mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private slots:
void on_Input_A_textChanged(const QString &arg1);

void on_add_clicked();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Can you post `mainwindow.h` too? That error looks like a `signal` not implemented

Answer (score 5):

Just delete (or implement) `on_Input_A_textChanged`:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_add_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

you probally deleted that method and forgot the declaration in the class.